# chmod not working immediately after creating file using touch

Tags: android, root, chmod, su

I have been trying to make a file in the protected storage of android ie data/data.
I understand this requires root access. So this is the code I have executed to create the file.
After this I chmod the file to 766, so that it is writable by the android app that just created it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            String app="some_installed_package";
            if(isPackageInstalled(app,getBaseContext())){
            try{
            Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

            DataOutputStream suStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            String filePath="/data/data/some_folder/file1.xml";
            String filePath2="/data/data/some_folder/file2.xml";
            try
            {
                suStream.writeBytes("touch "+filePath2+"\n");
                suStream.flush();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("App",e.getMessage());
            }
            try
            {
              suStream.writeBytes("chmod 0777 "+filePath2+ "\n");
              suStream.flush();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("App2",e.getMessage());
            }
            String ans="Error";
                try{
                    readFileAsString(filePath,filePath2);
                    ans="Done!";
                    //suStream.writeBytes("rm "+filePath+ "\n");
                    //suStream.writeBytes("mv "+filePath2+" "+filePath+"\n");
                    }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("App",(String)e.getMessage());

                }
                finally{
                    //suStream.writeBytes("chmod 0660 "+filePath+ "\n");
                    suStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
                    suStream.flush();
                    suStream.close();
                }

            }
        catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("App","Sudo not found!");
        }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"App not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void readFileAsString(String filePath,String filePath2) throws IOException
{
    String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line, results = "";
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
    {
        results += line + separator;
    }
    reader.close();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePath2);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    Log.e("App",results);
    try
    {
    bw.write(results);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("App",e.getMessage());
    }
    bw.close();
    }


}
```

The file does gets created but then I receive a "permission denied" error when I try to write on it.
To confirm the permission changes I open the file with a FILE MANAGER and find the permissions to be set as I had set them using the code.

Next without changing anything I re launch the app(now the file has already been created with the appropriate permission) it is writable and the everything goes as I wanted.

I dont understand what is going wrong here. I need to write immediately to the file after it has been created.

P.S My objective is to edit an XML file. The best method i found was to write to a temporary file with the changes in it as i require, then delete the original file and the rename the new file to the old one.

Comment: Speculation in the absence of a hard logic explanation, but what happens if you close the superuser subshell session *before* you try writing to the file?  Note that a (slightly) more secure choice might be to create the file in your private storage area within the data partition, and then have the superuser `mv` it to the desired destination, possibly changing the ownership - then you could leave it without the preferably avoided 0777 permission.

Comment: I tried closing and relaunching su after every command.
This too didnt help much.

Comment: @chris-stratton I got it working somehow by adding a sleep operation via a thread and then performing the write operation. I just can guess that the system was taking time to acknowledge the permission change. Please correct me if my guess is wrong.